# Zend Framework: Implement Zend_Acl_Resources

Tags: zend-framework, zend-acl

how should i implement Zend_Acl_Resources? do i have something like:

```
$acl->isAllowed()
```

in controller actions? i somehow think there maybe a better way ... but cant think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this in preDispatch in plugin or in preDispatch of Controller base class. There you have your request and you can check sth like this:

```
if($acl->isAllowed('resource'.$request->getControllerName().$request->getActionName())){
    return;
} else {
   //redirect to 403
}
```

You can also extend *resourceControllerAction* from *resourceController* to ensure the rights are always inherited. And that way you can simplify the ACL rules generation...

Comment: oh yes something like that will be more "dynamic". ... except maybe for some controller actions, i may need to include exceptions. eg. show some parts of a page but not others.

Comment: Other parts should be added via view helpers and they can be easily connected with ACL and return html block od '' if not allowed.